# applying preg_replace() generated unwanted symbols

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a function which is intended to format the output from `proc_open`.

```
 private function prepareOutput($output) {
        $output = htmlentities($output);
        $output = addslashes($output);
        $output = explode("\n", $output);
        $output = implode("</span><span>", $output);
        $output = sprintf("<span>%s</span>", $output);
        $output = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/", '\n', $output);
        $output = preg_replace('/\x1B\[0m(\x1B)/', "\x1B", $output);
        $output = preg_replace('/\x1B\[m/', '', $output);
        $output = preg_replace('/\x07/', '', $output);
        flush();
        return $output;
    }
```

I use it for miscellaneous Linux shell commands like this

```
prepareOutput(stream_get_contents($this->pipes[1]));
```

where the param can be,e.g. `ls`, `whoami` etc. The function works but generates some undesired chars to the output. For example for `exit` it gives the following output:

```
]0;Peppermint Terminal[01;32musr@usrfox-g50[01;34m ~ $[00m exit
logout
```

These *]0;* and *[01;34m* and *[00m* symbols are not wanted in the output. Where do they come from?

Comment: Those characters are your colored prompt. The prompt is visible only in the terminal, it is not present when you run a command using `proc_open()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are flags from the `bash` shell to change the colour of the console text. Usually you would get the program that you're using to return the value in clean text instead of with formatting.